# Should the shaliach tzibbur check the tzitzis of a tallis given to him to daven?

Tags: tzitzis, chazzan-prayer-leader, tallit-gadol, borrowing, inspection

Some shuls require the shaliach tzibbur to wear a tallis for mincha which is normally given to him from shul property. Is he required to check the tzitzis before wearing it?
Do we say that it would be “tircho detziburo” (a pain for the Community) to be kept waiting and anyway the tallis is probably kosher, or does he need to check it?

Comment: +1, but it's too specific: Same question applies to _maariv_, _shacharis_, _musaf, _n'ila_ (though that's generally someone married and thus wearing a _talis_ anyway), _baale k'ria_, _olim_, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He would have to check it if he is going to make a bracha on it.

One solution to this problem is too declare ownerless your share in the Shul's tallit thereby making the tallit a borrowed tallit which is not obligated in tzitzit. This way it doesn't matter if they are invalid and you won't be making a bracha anyway.

(Sources: Mishna Brurah [13 sk 15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=48), [8 sk 22 and Biur Halacha 8 sv Kodem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=26))

Comment: Thank you. The only thing is that in 8 sk22 MB goes on to write that the Acharonim say you need to check all the multiple pairs of tzitzis (even though you don't have to make a brocho on more than one). But it seems that the best you can do to avoid “tircho detziburo” at that time is to declare it ownerless. Gaboim should be encouraged to keep their talitot checked and kosher. This question was occasioned by taking off a talis after being Sh"Tz and finding it posul.

Comment: Yes, I was balancing that chumra against the shaat hadechak of tircha detzibura. But as you say, in the maskana it doesn't matter.

Comment: Why would you have an ownership share in it to declare ownerless?

Comment: @SethJ IIUC The entire community owns it beshutfut.